# SQL Job for SSIS Package with multiple config files

Tags: ssis, sql-job

How to Create a SQL job for SSIS Package having two configuration files saved in file configuration method(to make the same package run in two different servers) ?

Comment: I take it this is SSIS 2008 or something similiar (not 2012 or onwards?) If you have two config files, which one do you want to use at runtime? Or do you want to combine them. Can you explain what you are trying to do - perhaps there is an easier way.

Comment: If you're talking about two configs with different environments, normally you run them on different servers. With the same path on different servers having different configs.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid ,  Consider a package for getting data from database table to another table. I have created one manifest file for a package with two configuration files(for two different servers), I need to deploy the package along with respective configuration file, so that the work can be done on both servers(both severs having same tables, that's not an issue).

Comment: How do you want to decide at runtime which config to use? If you use two separate jobs this can be done

Comment: If you use two jobs, you use the `DTEXEC /Conf` command line switch to point at a different config file in each job. I recommend you do not use legacy packages if possible.

Comment: May I know the reason behind it @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Reason behind not using legacy configs? There are many.  Project deployment is easier in so many ways